# How to prove $\sigma$-additivity in a probability measure $F(x)=P((-\infty,x])$ given a distribution $F(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm in search of a little support up here, so thanks in advance.

So, lets say we have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B})$, and we want to construct a probability measure $P$ for a given distribution $F(x)$ by defining:
$F(x) = P((-\infty,x])$. And we want to construct this measure on $\mathcal{S}= \{ 
(a,b], -\infty, \leq a \leq b \leq +\infty  \}$.

If we define the probability measure as $P((a,b])= F(b) - F(a)$ How to veryfy this is a valid probability measure? I have looked at Resnick's book, page 61, but cannot understand and I'm looking for an alternative and more intuitive way to approach the problem.

So far, what I think that must be proved is that we can represent $R$ as a countable disjoint union of open intervals, then, sigma additivity will come easily.

Comment: The main thing to verify is countable additivity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes exactly, that's what i'm thinking of, but running out of ideas of how to represent $R$ as a countable disjoint union of open intervals.. Once I have that, I'm done I think. Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to deal with the question, why it's enough to consider a content on $$\mathcal{S}= \{ 
(a,b], -\infty, \leq a \leq b \leq +\infty  \}$$ and you get a measure on $\mathcal{B}$ (hint: [Caratheodory's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem)) but just want to know if $P(\Bbb R) = 1$ you can easily think about the following fact using telescoping series:

Obviously you can write $\Bbb R$ as the following disjoint union $$\Bbb R = \bigcup_{k\in\Bbb Z} (-k,k]$$
Then it holds: $$\begin{align*} P(\Bbb R) &= \sum_{k\in \Bbb Z} P(-k,k] \\ &= \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty P(-k,k] \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k = n}^m P(-k,k] \\ &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{m\to\infty}  F(m) - F(n) = 1 - 0 = 1\end{align*}$$